# Usage of bid verb

Tags: grammar

Bid him *do* it. This sentence seems awkward.

Would it not make more sense to write Bid him *to do* it.

I thought that bid could be changed to ask but the aforementioned sentence implies otherwise.

Comment: The reason your example is "awkward" is because almost nobody uses ***bid*** in this sense today. But [back when it **was** in use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+bade+him+speak%2CI+bade+him+to+speak&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20bade%20him%20speak%3B%2Cc0) the associated verb (referencing something someone ***was bade do,*** if you can stand to read such an awkward sequence! :) was normally given as an ***unmarked infinitive*** (i.e. - the "infinitive marker" ***to*** wasn't normally included). Just don't use it yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage bid + personal pronoun + verb infinitive is correct but somewhat literary.

> Bid verb
>   If you bid someone do something, you ask or invite them to do
>   it. [literary]
>   **They all smiled at him and bade him eat. [VERB noun infinitive]**
>   I dare say he did as he was bidden. [be VERB-ed]

[Bid (Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bid)

'Bid', when used this way, can often be replaced by 'ask to' but when it was more widely used it could also be used to describe an instruction e.g. to a servant or subordinate - I bid my maid bring me some tea, or a strong suggestion - John was soaked from the rain and I bid him go indoors and get dry. When we wish to suggest that A is in fear or awe of B and is obedient in a cowardly or deplorable way, we can still say that A does B's bidding.